# why is my ping to 10.8.0.1 going through the public internet

Tags: openvpn

(this question was totally different before. becouse of a lack of basic knowledge mixed with paranoia, i was scared and thought that something was compromised in my lan...)
now i edited it completely, so that maybe someone can improve of it

i am playing around with serverconfiguration and openvpn.
everything in my openvpntests should only happen within my lan...

```
in the client.conf:
remote "ServersLanIp" 1194 
(somthing like 192.168.2.123)
```

i was pinging the openvpn server's vpn-ip-address when there was no vpn-connection established.

```
ping 10.8.0.1
PING 10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 195.xx.xxx.xxx icmp_seq=7 Packet filtered
From 195.xx.xxx.xxx icmp_seq=8 Packet filtered
```

195...??? i did a traceroute:

```
traceroute to 195.xx.xxx.xxx(195.xx.xxx.xxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
```

`showed some route to the internet`

openvpn-server and openvpn-client are both in the same lan, why is the ping going through the public internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing out of the ordinary in anything that you reported. I'm not sure I understand why you're scared or why you think there's a compromise, so it's hard for me to figure out what I need to explain to you. You put a packet on the public Internet that doesn't belong there, it followed the default route for awhile, and the first machine that checked rejected it. What's so strange about that?

Comment: does that mean, that if the connection between client and server is not established yet, there is no route to my lan-openvpn-server, and the ping is searchin 10.8.0.1 through the default route, which is my connection to the public internet?

Comment: @coffeekid Correct. You should be polite (and protect your privacy) by adding either a null route or a firewall rule to prevent such packets from following your router's default route.

Comment: You should configure your router not to send packets with private destination addresses to your Internet service provider. You can do this either with a packet filter or with a null route. This will also protect your privacy -- you don't want "leftover" packets following your default route if the VPN closes.

Comment: i know tried this command: "iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.8.0.1 ! -o tun0 -j DROP"  and when i ping 10.8.0.1 now it says "ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted" very nice!

Comment: ok, i still can ping 10.8.0.3, so the better command: iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.8.0/24 ! -o tun0 -j DROP (just posting this for other newbies like me :-) )